# What happens to non-believers or believers of other religions after death?

Tags: atheism, soteriology

What happens (according to Christians) to people who specificially rejected the idea of God, the Bible and the christian teachings after they die?

Is there a difference to people who believed in another deity, maybe even several deities?

<sub>We have seen questions what [happens to people who have never heard about Jesus](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/what-happens-to-people-who-have-never-heard-about-jesus), [unborn babies](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/256/what-happens-to-unborn-unbaptized-babies-who-die) and [children](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/126/do-children-go-to-heaven). I did not see that question before, so I asked right away. Additionally I don't ask [if we can go to heaven](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1809/can-an-atheist-go-to-heaven), but simply what happens after our life has ended.</sub>

Comment: A perfect answer to this question includes a variety of views, from the common "acceptance of Christ leads to Heaven, all others go to Hell" to Christian Universalism, Annihilationism, and other ideas on the subject.

Comment: Related: [Is Hell eternal, or do some/all escape it?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/144)

Comment: @IanPugsley Agreed, there is absolutely no one agreed upon answer from this one, there is a spectrum of beliefs depending on who you talk to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an atheist go to heaven?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1809/can-an-atheist-go-to-heaven)

Comment: @Waggers, it's not the question **if** non-believers can go to heaven, but **what** happens, so I see no duplicate..

Comment: There is no agreement on this. If you ask universalists they will give a different answer than other Christians...

Comment: Please bring this old question into current site guidelines. Thanks. Resource for your convenience: [Question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Bible is very clear that all atheists and non-believers will be sent to the Lake of Fire after they die.  It even goes further than that by specifying a list of people that are not accepted (which covers more than your question!):

> [Revelations 21:8 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelations%2021:8&version=NIV)
>   But the cowardly, the unbelieving, the vile, the murderers, the sexually immoral, those who practice magic arts, the idolaters and all liars—they will be consigned to the fiery lake of burning sulfur. This is the second death.

To answer the question, it's pretty clear that the Bible does not distinguish between "non-believers" (atheist, agnostic, or what have you) and "believers of other religions".  When it says "the unbelieving" it refers to all non-Christians.

Furthermore, it's the *belief* in God that brings salvation, not the works.  We can see from this verse that it's what's in a man's heart that determines his salvation.  Every one of these evils can be directly related to a problem in the person's heart.

> [Acts 16:31 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2016:31&version=NIV)
>   They replied, “Believe in the Lord Jesus, and you will be saved—you and your household.”

However, works are an outpouring *from* faith:

> [John 14:15 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014:15&version=NIV)
>   If you love me, keep my commands.

And without the faith that produces works, there is no actual faith behind it:

> [James 2:14-18 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%202:14&version=NIV)
>   14 What good is it, my brothers and sisters, if someone claims to have faith but has no deeds? Can such faith save them? 15 Suppose a brother or a sister is without clothes and daily food. 16 If one of you says to them, “Go in peace; keep warm and well fed,” but does nothing about their physical needs, what good is it? 17 In the same way, faith by itself, if it is not accompanied by action, is dead.
>
> 18 But someone will say, “You have faith; I have deeds.”
>
> Show me your faith without deeds, and I will show you my faith by my deeds.

Ultimately, to answer the question, all non-believers (people who do not believe in any god, the Christian God, or who believe in another God) along with all people who claim to believe in God but do not have a solid faith will end up in the lake of fire.

Comment: @Sven, according to the Bible - there is no distinction between "big" and "little" sins: if you have broken one law, you are guilty of all of it

Comment: @Sven that's why all sin is equal. There are no 'small' sins. see this answer for an explanation http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/are-sins-sinful-because-they-are-inherently-acts-of-badness-or-because-they-are-a/2115#2115     ,   But that is the good news of the gospel that "While we were still sinners, Christ Died for us" Christ died to pay for all our sins, but if you reject him you stay in the same condition you are already living in, condemnation, If you accept Christ you pass from death to life. see John 3:16-18

Comment: "Atheist" and "agnostic" aren't mutually exclusive. In fact, most atheists you'll find are agnostic atheists like myself.

Comment: @Atheist: Actually using dictionary definitions they ARE mutually exclusive. Atheists claim to _know_ that there is no God, Agnostics claim it's not possible to have that kind of _know_ledge.

Comment: @Caleb That is the wrong definition. The correct definition is (Oxford Dictionary): "a person who **does not believe** in the existence of God or gods:". An atheist is someone who *lacks belief* in a god or gods; it has nothing to do with knowledge.

Comment: @caleb, [It's a common misconception](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_MDZPs8ROJXE/TNx7UFqbaII/AAAAAAAAB9M/XDfxPwyBVpA/s1600/Gnostic_Agnostic_Atheist.png)

Comment: But what the Lake of Fire is is another question. Some say it's just annihilation.

Comment: @Sven, that's a pretty good diagram; probably is more accurately a triangle, however. All the way down on "agnostic" there is much less difference between theist and atheist than there is all the way up on gnostic.

Comment: How long would we burn in fire?

Comment: @Meysam Comments are to be used to refine the post, not to ask new questions.  If you want to know, there's a button at the top of this (and every) page labeled "Ask Question".

Comment: Agnosticism and gnosticism are epistemological stances, theism and atheism are theological stances. I believe I have met people who fall into each of the 4 possible intersections of those.

Comment: The position presented here is not a universal among Christians, but is in fact a minority even among theistic Christians.  The answer should be edited to reflect that.

Comment: How about pithecanthropus erectus who was born before christianity exists?

Answer (score 4):

I would just like to add that the book of Romans talks about those who have not heard the gospel and those of other religions.

> Romans 2 Let God Be the Judge  1 So do you think that you can judge
>   those other people? You are wrong. You too are guilty of sin. You
>   judge them, but you do the same things they do. So when you judge
>   them, you are really condemning yourself. 2 God judges all who do such
>   things, and we know his judgment is right. 3 And since you do the same
>   things as those people you judge, surely you understand that God will
>   punish you too. How could you think you would be able to escape his
>   judgment? 4 God has been kind to you. He has been very patient,
>   waiting for you to change. But you think nothing of his kindness.
>   Maybe you don’t understand that God is kind to you so that you will
>   decide to change your lives.
>
> 5 But you are so stubborn! You refuse to change. So you are making
>   your own punishment greater and greater. You will be punished on the
>   day when God will show his anger. On that day everyone will see how
>   right God is to judge people. 6 He will reward or punish everyone for
>   what they have done. 7 Some people live for God’s glory, for honor,
>   and for life that cannot be destroyed. They live for those things by
>   always continuing to do good. God will give eternal life to them. 8
>   But others are selfish and refuse to follow truth. They follow evil.
>   God will show his anger and punish them. 9 He will give trouble and
>   suffering to everyone who does evil—to the Jews first and also to
>   those who are not Jews. 10 But he will give glory, honor, and peace to
>   everyone who does good—to the Jews first and also to those who are not
>   Jews. 11 God judges everyone the same. It doesn’t matter who they are.
>
> **12 People who have the law and those who have never heard of the law
>   are all the same when they sin. People who don’t have the law and are
>   sinners will be lost. And, in the same way, those who have the law and
>   are sinners will be judged by the law. 13 Hearing the law does not
>   make people right with God. They will be right before him only if they
>   always do what the law says.**
>
> **14 Those who are not Jews don’t have the law. But when they naturally
>   do what the law commands without even knowing the law, then they are
>   their own law. This is true even though they don’t have the written
>   law. 15 They show that in their hearts they know what is right and
>   wrong, the same as the law commands, and their consciences agree.
>   Sometimes their thoughts tell them that they have done wrong, and this
>   makes them guilty. And sometimes their thoughts tell them that they
>   have done right, and this makes them not guilty.**
>
> 16 All this will happen on the day when God will judge people’s
>   secret thoughts through Jesus Christ. This is part of the Good News
>   that I tell everyone.

Just thought it worth mentioning

Answer (score 2):

What happens  to  people, who  reject  God  and  the  bible, after they die?

They  go  to  the  grave  and  remain  there,  until  the  second  coming  of  Jesus  Christ.
Is  there  a  difference  to  those people  who  believe  in  other  deites?  No.

John 5;28,29

Marvel  not  at  this:  for  the  hour  is  coming:  in  the  which  all  that  are  in  the  graves  shall  hear  his  voice, 29  And  shall  come  forth;  they  that  have  done  good,  unto  the  resurrection  of  life;  and  they  that  have  done  evil,  unto  the  resurrection  of  damnation.

Matthew 13;30

Let  both  grow  together  until  the  harvest;  and  in the  time  of  harvest  I  will  say  unto  the  reapers,  Gather  ye  together  first  the  tares,  and  bind  them  in  bundles  to  burn  them:  but  gather  the  wheat  into   my  barn.

1 Timothy 4;12

Let  no  man  despise  thy  youth;  but  be  thou  an  example  of  the  believers,  in  word,  in  conversation,  in  charity,  in  spirit,  in  faith,  in  purity.

2 Corinthians 6;14

Be  ye  not  unequally  yoked  together  with  unbelievers:  for  what  fellowship  hath  righteouness  with  unrighteousness?  and  what  communion  hath  light  with  darkness?

Acts 2;25-27

For  David  speaketh  concerning  him,  I  foresaw  the  LORD  always  before  my  face,  for  he  is  on  my  right  hand,  that  I  should  not  be  moved:  26  Therefore  did  my  heart  rejoice,  and  my  tongue  was  glad;  moreover  also  my  flesh  shall  rest  in  hope:  27 Because  thou  wilt  not  leave  my  soul  in  hell,  neither  wilt  thou  suffer  thine  Holy  One  to  see  corruption.

After  the  crucifixion,  Jesus  went  to  the  grave  and  remained  there  until  the  resurrection.